# Why might HTML internal links work when JavaScript is disabled, but not when it's enabled? Cookies?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, cookies, hyperlink

On this web page, https://roseriverway.com/learn-to-paint/, I'm trying to figure out why the internal links on the three headers of this page, "Supply Kits", "Workshops", and "Private Paint Parties" are only redirecting to the corresponding headers of the page when I right click the link, then select open "Open Link in New Tab". I find this to be the case in both the Chromium based Brave, and Firefox. I do not want to have to right click the link, but instead simply be able to click it and have the pageview be re-directed to the corresponding header. This is how the page used to work, but I'm not sure what change may have broken this functionality. WordPress has updated since that functionality originally worked, but I'm not sure how that may have impacted the functionality.

Here is the header that I want to link to the header further down on the page:

```
<a href="#supply-kits">Supply Kits</a>
```

And here is how I have the header below that I want the internal link to go to (without having to open the page in a new tab).

```
<br id="supply-kits"><br><h3>Supply Kits</h3>
```

Thanks to some answers provided below, I found that the links work with JavaScript disabled. I also found the following issue message in the browser would pop up after clicking one of the links with JavaScript enabled (this message did not appear when JS was disabled). I think the next step for me is to figure out how to modify the attributes of the cookie.

Issue error message:

Indicate whether to send a cookie in a cross-site request by specifying its SameSite attribute
Because a cookie's SameSite attribute was not set or is invalid, it defaults to SameSite=Lax, which prevents the cookie from being sent in a cross-site request. This behavior protects user data from accidentally leaking to third parties and cross-site request forgery.

Resolve this issue by updating the attributes of the cookie:
Specify SameSite=None and Secure if the cookie should be sent in cross-site requests. This enables third-party use.
Specify SameSite=Strict or SameSite=Lax if the cookie should not be sent in cross-site requests

1 cookie
Learn more: SameSite cookies explained

Comment: can you try using a span instead of a break tag?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your console?

Answer (score 0):

Your links are OK. And they work if you disable JavaScript in your browser.

So some JS is interfering with the way the anchors work.